# Create child tables from table with INSERT INTO and no duplicate

Tags: php, sql, join, duplicates

To be clear, this what I need:

[image: tables]

I get my data for **table "recap" from a JSON file**.

**What I need is two tables:**

First: **table "Voyage"** with no duplicate (I try a lot but all failed)

Second: **table "simplifiee"** which is the same as "recap" but with a ID voyage column from table "voyage" (I'm pretty sure I need a JOIN, left, full, other.. but not enough good at doing this..)

Let me know if you don't understand.

This is my code:

```html
<?php
     
    require 'database.php';
      $pdo = Database::connect();
      $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// JSON content //
        $json = file_get_contents("https://xxx");
// Décode //
        $parsed_json = json_decode($json);

foreach ($parsed_json->{'results'} as $result)
{

// Parsed JSON //
            $date = $result->{'xxx'};
            $transporteur = $result->{'xxx'};
            $depart = $result->{'xxx'};
            $arrivee = $result->{'xxx'};
            $prixhaut = $result->{'xxx'};
            $prixbas = $result->{'xxx'};

// Table "recap" Creation //

      $sql = "INSERT INTO recap (date,transporteur,depart,arrivee,prixhaut,prixbas) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
      $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
      $q->execute(array($date,$transporteur,$depart,$arrivee,$prixhaut,$prixbas));

}

      Database::disconnect();
?>
```

Comment: Post the code you have done so far so people can enhance or fix it.

Comment: you got it. Tx for you interest

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: im using phpmyadmin

Comment: So MySQL is your DBMS as phpmyadmin is a GUI console to MySQL written in PHP.